# How to use Examples with only one variable in Gherkin Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin, cucumber-java

I am trying to write Gherkins with only one variable in a Scenario Outline. I see an error "1 out of bounds for length" when I try running my feature file. However if I add a second variable (another column and another variable) this will pass.

Is there a way to write Scenario Outlines with just one variable instead of two or more? If so, how?

Thank you!

Example A

```
Feature: Is this a valid fruit?

  Scenario Outline: Is this a fruit 
    When I ask whether <fruit> is a fruit
    Then I should see "Yes this is a fruit" message

  Examples:
    | fruit     |
    | Kiwi      | 
    | Apple     | 
    | Pineapple | 

Gives me an error "1 out of bounds for length"
```

I can change it to the below format and it passes, but I want to avoid adding an entire column with the same string just to make the Cucumber Gherkins pass.

Example B

```
Feature: Is this a valid fruit?

  Scenario Outline: Is this a fruit 
    When I ask whether <fruit> is a fruit
    Then I should see <message> message

  Examples:
    | fruit     | message 
    | Kiwi      | "Yes this is a fruit"
    | Apple     | "Yes this is a fruit"
    | Pineapple | "Yes this is a fruit"
```

How can we make Example A valid and pass? Thanks!

Comment: It's possible that the second | in the line denotes the start of a second column. Try it with just one pipe character before the value and see. I'm not convinced, but try it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, removing the last pipe character causes a syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what works for me with Cucumber 7.4.1:

```java
package so;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;

public class StepDef {
    @When("I ask whether {word} is a fruit")
    public void i_ask_whether_kiwi_is_a_fruit(String value) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    @Then("I should see {string} message")
    public void i_should_see_message(String string) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Which with this feature file:

```
Feature: Is this a valid fruit?

  Scenario Outline: Is this a fruit
    When I ask whether <fruit> is a fruit
    Then I should see "Yes this is a fruit" message

  Examples:
    | fruit     |
    | Kiwi      |
    | Apple     |
    | Pineapple |
```

gives:

```
Kiwi
Yes this is a fruit
Apple
Yes this is a fruit
Pineapple
Yes this is a fruit
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! Unfortunately, I still see the error.  I have Cucumber version 7.2.3 and to keep consistent with other teammates I might not be able to upgrade the version. If you add a Given I am on the question page and I am logged in before the When keywords, does yours still work?

Comment: I believe this is pretty basic thing and hardly depends on particular minor cucumber version. Frankly I'm not getting why you have issues with my code. I just took scenario from your example. And step defs are independent from each other so that adding more steps should not actually impact how well particular step is handled.

Comment: I realized it was a third party issue and this formatting is correct. Thanks for the help!